Qt framework on Clion on windows will not output qDebug()
I am developing a GUI application with Qt framework on clion on windows. Build and run works as intended.
But when I try to use qDebug() to output information on console or terminal the system gives nothing. There is no crash.
what I tried:

ticked "Run Configuration"->"Run in external console" and "Run Configuration"->"Emulate terminal in the output console".

When "Run Configuration"->"Run in external console" is ticked, the console outputs runnerw.exe: AttachConsole failed with error 6: The handle is invalid. error message.

used std::cout, the result is same.

added below environment variables for "Run Configurations"
QT_LOGGING_RULES=*debug=true;QT_ASSUME_STDERR_HAS_CONSOLE=1

ticked Registry cidr.debugger.gdb.workaround.windows.forceExternalConsole.


System info:

Windows 10
Qt 6.7.2
clion 2024.1.4

